# Write down an inverse matrix in terms of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$B^3-2B^2+3B=0$
I need to write it down in terms of $B^{-1}$ (inverse of it) 
 I know how that $BB^{-1}=I$ but seems it wont help to find $B^{-1}$ what kind of method do i have to use ?

Comment: Which "it" do you need to write down in terms of $B^{-1}$?
Or do you mean you need to write down $B^{-1}$ in terms of $B$?

Comment: That equation need to be written down in terms of inverse of B^-1

Comment: Ok, $B^3-3B^2+3B=0$, we multiply it by $B^{-3}$ an we got $I-3B^{-1}+3B^{-2}=0$. Is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $B^{-1}$ exists multiply both sides by $B^{-1}$ to get 
$$B^{-1}B^3-2B^{-1}B^2+3B^{-1}B=B^{-1}0$$
this is the same as saying
$$B^2-2B+3I=0$$
Multiply again by $B^{-1}$ to get
$$B^{-1}B^2-2B^{-1}B+3B^{-1}I=B^{-1}0$$
The expression above is the same as 
$$B-2I+3B^{-1}=0$$
This gives you the inverse in terms of the matrix itself
$$B^{-1}=\frac{1}{3}(2I-B)$$
Unless you want to convert the original equation in terms of $B^{-1}$ then following the same steps you would get to $$B^{-1}-2(B^{-1})^2+3(B^{-1})^3=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually the method is just write the equation $3x=2x^2-x^3 \Rightarrow 1=\frac13(2x-x^2)$[if $B^{-1}$ exists then only]$=\frac13(2-x)x$ . From here put $x=B$ & $1=I$ then consider $B'=\frac13(2I-B)$ then see BB'=I=B'B. hence B is invertible and $B'=B^{-1}$.

Note all this process can only be done if $B^{-1}$ exists. It may be possible that $B^{-1}$ does not exist [just consider the $0$ matrix.]